# .NET console app not reading config.json

Tags: c#, .net, json, configuration, configurationmanager

While building a .net console app which uses the new `ConfigurationBuilder` implementation for what used to be `appSettings`, I've run into a problem.

I have the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("config.json");
        var config = builder.Build();

        if (config["Azure"] != null)
        {
            ;
        }
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `config.json` file is in the same directory and looks like this:

```
{
  "Azure": {
    "Storage": {
      "ConnectionString": "...",
      "ContainerName": "..."
    }
  },
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "..."
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "RecordProgress": "..."
  }
}
```

But the `config` object contains no keys.

I read somewhere that if the file path passed to `AddJsonFile` can't be found then it throws a `FileNotFoundException` but in my code that exception is never thrown.

So presuming the config.json file *can* be found, why are the settings not being loaded?

Answer (score 7):

My original answer was off the mark. Here's an updated version. This is based on the recently released RC2.

The current runtime will throw `FileNotFoundException` if the config file isn't found. The `AddJsonFile()` extension method takes an optional parameter called `optional` that, if true, will cause the method not to throw.

I added `config.json` and it doesn't get copied to the bin directory, so I had to specify the location using the `SetBasePath()` extension method. This is what the Web project templates do in Startup, using `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath`. In console apps, you can use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("config.json");

var config = builder.Build();
```

Finally, the `config["Key"]` indexer didn't work for me. Instead, I had to use the `GetSection()` extension method. So your example config file above might be accessed with:

```
// var result = config["Logging"];
var section = config.GetSection("Logging");
var result = section["RecordProgress"];
```

I left the old answer for the time being.

Old answer:
I found a possible solution here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4481.

Quoting from the issue.

> Thanks for the repro project. Looks like you need to update the
>   project.json file to have the "content" node and have Config.json
>   specified here.
>
> Example:
>   https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/src/MusicStore/project.json#L22

It appears that a new content element may be required in your `project.json`.

`...
  "content": [
    "Areas",
    "Views",
    "wwwroot",
    "config.json",
    "web.config"
  ],
  ...`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Todd but this had no effect when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

config.json was in the correct directory and it was still not found.

The solution:
config.json contained a typo that broke the json syntax. After fixing the json syntax/format in config.json everything worked.